# Problem with program output

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

Below is my program and im having a problem with the determinant function.

File input is:

```
2
1 0
0 1
3
8 9 1
3 5 2
-2 3 -1
0
```

and for the second matrix it is reading nan for the result of the determinant function for matrix two in the input file, any ideas for what could be going wrong with my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const int maxsize = 10;

ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

void transpose (double omatrix[][maxsize],double tmatrix [][maxsize], int array_size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < array_size; j++)
        {
            tmatrix[j][i] = omatrix[i][j];
        }


    }
}

void sub (double omatrix[][maxsize], double smatrix[][maxsize], int array_size, int i, int j)
{
    int counter1 = 0, counter2 = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < array_size; a++)
    {
        if (a != i)
        {
            for (int b = 0; b < array_size; b++)
            {
                if (b != j)
                {
                    smatrix[counter1][counter2] = omatrix[a][b];
                    counter2++;
                }
            }
            counter1++;
        }
    }
}

double determininant(double original_matrix[][maxsize], int array_size)
{
    double D = 0.0, temp[maxsize][maxsize];

    if(array_size == 1)
    {
        return original_matrix[0][0];
    }

    else if(array_size == 2)
    {
        return (original_matrix[0][0] * original_matrix[1][1]) - (original_matrix[0][1] * original_matrix[1][0]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        sub (original_matrix,temp,array_size, 0, i);
        D += pow(-1.0,i) * original_matrix[0][i] * determininant(temp, array_size - 1);
    }
    return D;
}

void inverse(double omatrix[][maxsize], int array_size, double imatrix[][maxsize])
{
    double D = determininant(omatrix, array_size);
    double c[maxsize][maxsize];

    if (D != 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < array_size; j++)
                {
                    sub (omatrix, c, array_size, i, j);
                    imatrix[j][i] = pow(-1.0, i+j) * determininant( c, array_size - 1) / D;
                }
            }
    }
}

void mult(double omatrix[][maxsize], double imatrix[][maxsize], double pmatrix[][maxsize], int array_size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < array_size; j++)
                {
                    pmatrix[i][j] = 0;

                    for(int k = 0; k < array_size; k++)
                    {
                        pmatrix[i][j] += omatrix[i][k] *imatrix[k][j];
                    }
                }
            }
}

void print (const double m[][maxsize], int array_size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < array_size; j++)
                {
                    fout << m[i][j] << "  ";
                }
                fout << "\n";
            }
            fout << "\n";
}


int main()
{
    double original_matrix[maxsize][maxsize],
           inverse_matrix [maxsize][maxsize],
           transposed_matrix[maxsize][maxsize],
           product_matrix [maxsize][maxsize],
           D;


    int array_size;

    fout.setf(ios::fixed);
    fout.precision(2);

    char File_Name[10];
    cout << "Please enter a name for the output file";
    cin >> File_Name;

    fin.open ("input.txt");
    fout.open (File_Name);

    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file opening failed. \n";
        return 0;
    }

    while(fin >> array_size)
    {
        if(array_size != 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < array_size; j++)
                {
                    fin >> original_matrix[i][j];
                }
            }

            fout << "THE ORIGIONAL ARRAY! \n";
            print (original_matrix, array_size);
            transpose (original_matrix, transposed_matrix, array_size);
            fout << "THE TRANSPOSED VIRSION! \n";
            print (transposed_matrix, array_size);
            fout << determininant(original_matrix, array_size) << "\n\n";
            inverse(original_matrix, array_size, inverse_matrix);
            print (inverse_matrix, array_size);
            mult(original_matrix, inverse_matrix, product_matrix, array_size);
            print (product_matrix, array_size);


        }
    }

    fin.close();
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
THE ORIGIONAL ARRAY! 
1.00  0.00  
0.00  1.00  

THE TRANSPOSED VIRSION! 
1.00  0.00  
0.00  1.00  

1.00

1.00  -0.00  
-0.00  1.00  

1.00  0.00  
0.00  1.00  

THE ORIGIONAL ARRAY! 
8.00  9.00  1.00  
3.00  5.00  2.00  
-2.00  3.00  -1.00  

THE TRANSPOSED VIRSION! 
8.00  3.00  -2.00  
9.00  5.00  3.00  
1.00  2.00  -1.00  

nan                              <--------------------- is wrong should be -78.00
                                                        which makes the next 2 mess up.
0.00  -0.00  0.00  
-0.00  0.00  -0.00  
0.00  -0.00  0.00  

0.00  0.00  0.00  
0.00  0.00  0.00  
0.00  0.00  0.00
```

Comment: Yeah, why else would i want to do all this with a matrix....lol

Comment: Are you sure your arrays are being read in correctly?

Comment: positive because everything else works fine and the first one runs through fine.

Comment: `fin >> original_matrix[i][j];` I don't see any error handling...

Comment: int vs float? (I haven't read code yet...)

Comment: Good luck i've been looking for like an hour.

Comment: Clue you dont execute the D = pow(......... code until your array size is greater than 2. Run it through the debugger with a break on this line and all should (perhaps) become clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to reset `counter2` in `sub(...)`. So you are copying into the wrong place in the result matrix, and using uninitialized memory in your calculations.

(The moral of the story is to declare variables in the smallest possible scope where you actually need them.)